# warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers

Tags: c, pointers

I am observing error "warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers " because of below line of code. Going through other similar questions on SO I understand (not 100 percent) it is because of

-->  const char* EmployeeList[]  and my declaration in qsort of EmployeeList

```
    #define Elements(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof((array)[0]))

   const char *EmployeeList[] =
   {
      "Larry Page", "Sergy Brin", "Sundar Pichai", "Merrisa Mayer"
   };

// called from main
SortEmployee(EmployeeList, Elements(EmployeeList));

int Compare(const void *elemA, const void *elemB)
{
 ...
}

void SortEmployee(const char *EmployeeList[], size_t EmployeeCount)
{
    qsort(EmployeeList, EmployeeCount, sizeof(EmployeeList[0]), Compare);
}
```

However I am unable to resolve it- Any pointers how to do it for array of strings.

Comment: I have a feeling that the problem is with the `Compare` function, not the `EmployeeList` array. Posting a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make this question a lot easier to answer.

Comment: I have modified the code part and put much more relevant part of code. if Its not sufficient - will put the entire code - just trying to avoid cluster.

Comment: I see no problems with that code, the `Compare` function looks correct. I filled in the blanks to make an MCVE, and it compiles without error or warning (using clang with -Wall), and runs fine. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using microsoft compiler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is `qsort` *does not* declare its argument as `const`, while your code *does*. That means `qsort` may (in theory) change data, pointed by `EmployeeList`. So, the compiler reports this error.

Here is the official example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k77bkb8d.aspx

How ever, here is a simple version to demonstrate my idea:

```
void foo(char* a) {
   *a = '1'; // I got pointer to char, and changed this char!
}


int main() {
   const char *a = "A"; // I have "CONSTANT POINTER": it points to CONSTANT memory, that CAN NOT be changed (by the way, string constants can't in many environments).
   foo(a); // I pass it to my function, that will change it.
   return 0;
}
```

Image your compiler stores `a` in read-only memory (It can, because we told it "this is a pointer to READ ONLY data"). You then modify it (in `main` function). Something bad may happen. So, the compiler warns you "hey, you pass a pointer to *constant* data to some function, that *does not know* that this data is constant and *may* change it"

Comment: Of course it will change data pointed by `EmployeeList` : it's the pointers it's supposed to sort. The `const` only applies to the next level of dereferencing.

Comment: @user996142 - Thanks for the detailed answer. I do understand that and I tried to point out that problem in my question - I was wondering is there a way to overcome it - assuming I cannot change   const char *EmployeeList[] =
   {
      "Larry Page", "Sergy Brin", "Sundar Pichai", "Merrisa Mayer"
   };

Comment: I just changed void SortEmployee(const char *EmployeeList[], size_t EmployeeCount) to void SortEmployee(char *EmployeeList[], size_t EmployeeCount) and I no longer see it  - Thanks for the help !!