# Can't understand "warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers" in my c program

Tags: c, visual-c++

I've got message `warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers` when compiling my C program.

I've seen some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973854/warning-c4090-function-different-const-qualifiers), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304078/warning-c4090-initializing-different-unaligned-qualifiers) and even [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4090?view=vs-2017). But I still don't understand how are they related with my problem. For compiling I use Visual C++ 2015 x64 Native Build Tools Command Prompt. 
I know that it's because of using `const` in function declaration. But array is not changing. So what's the deal?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_array(const int a[], int n)
{
    int *p, sum;

    sum = 0;
    for (p = a; p < a + n; p++)
        sum += *p;

    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf("%d", sum_array(a, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Program works well, I just want to understand why I get this warning.

Comment: Side note: You can write sum_array(a, sizeof(a) / size(*a)); You don't have to count the number of elements yourself and hard code it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised it is only a warning. In C++ this would be entirely ill-formed.

Your function takes a `const int*`, which you then assign to an `int*`.

That is not `const`-correct.

I guess you meant `const int *p`??

Comment: I've taken `sum_array()` code from [here](http://knking.com/books/c2/answers/c12.html) (see #6). So maybe it's just outdated? A book is relatively old.

Comment: @Petr Books can have mistakes